# Window Manager: Add the maximize option to any window (even if the UI disabled the option)

Tags: window-manager, window, user-interface, maximize, binary-flags

Some graphical programs make use of a window which the user can scale unlimitedly but still disable the maximize option (for whichever dumb reason).

[EDIT]: The window might be a subwindow of another window (don't know the technical term), and it is the only window (of the application instance) that can be interacted with until it is closed, like a dilog.

I use Linux Mint with Cinnamon, using X11 I believe.

Although this would help temporarily, I am ultimately not looking for a window manager command line which resizes the window but I want to change the window flags themselves, without having access to the source code and without being specific to one particular program.

Rant: It appears to me that some programmers or UI designers want to force their view on a program, inconsiderate of the needs and preferences of the end user, ignorant of what actually is the optimal work flow in the end.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I asked a related question [software to automate changes to windows and window properties?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35456/software-to-automate-changes-to-windows-and-window-properties) about 6 years ago.

The answer I found was [devilspie](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/DevilsPie) which is no longer maintained, or its successor [devilspie2](https://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/) (read my answer on softwarerecs for a summary of both).

Both are packaged for Debian, so I'd guess they're in Mint too.

Here's the package description for `devilspie2`:

```
Package: devilspie2
Version: 0.43-5
Installed-Size: 121
Maintainer: Debian QA Group <packages@qa.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0),
         liblua5.1-0, libwnck-3-0 (>= 3.2.0), libx11-6
Description-en: Lua-based window matching utility
 Devilspie2 is a window matching utility, allowing the user to perform
 scripted actions on windows as they are created. For example, you can
 script a terminal program to always be positioned at a specific screen
 position, or automatically position a window on a specific workspace.
 .
 It is a continuation of Ross Burton's project Devilspie, with the most
 significant change that the symbolic expressions of that project are
 replaced with a Lua interpreter.
Homepage: https://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner to maximize the current window using `wmctrl` would be the following:

```
sleep 1; wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

Comment: It works in general, but this **does not work for the window I am interested in** though, it might have to do with it being a subwindow.